# Shall I give it up when the job requires candidates to have some kind of IT cert

Tags: new-job, certification

I have been working as an assistant in a cake shop for more than 4 years.
Recently, I am thinking to change my job field because I have seen a computer company nearby have a vancancy for a clerk, but the job requires some kind of IT cert (related to word processing) which I don't have.

Given that situation, shall I give it up? Or I should send an application first and wait for their call for an interview?

I would like some advice from the experts here that, when there are some job vancancies available which interest you but you don't have the required certificates (e.g. MS Office certs), does this mean that you should give it up and look for some other jobs instead.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just get some kind of IT cert?  There are easy enough cert that don't cost much.   But it does not hurt to apply without a cert.  Most certification of over rated.  Too many people just study for the certification and don't really know the product.

Comment: @ Paparazzi. Please write it as an answer. It is so helpful and I want to vote it up.

Comment: Do many jobs that interest you require a particular certification? Or is it more like there is one job out of 10 that require a particular cert?

Comment: Career advice is off topic for the site,  voting to close.

Comment: I'm of a mind with Wandering Dev, though if this question is reworded to a general case it might make sense. @kitty Consider asking in [chat] when you have a question like this that's a poor fit for the main site. You might even link the specific certificate required there because frankly, I doubt a "word processing" certificate would be worth the paper it's printed on.

Comment: Look at it this way: you have nothing to lose ;)

Comment: Do you have any skills that the certification is intended to verify?

Comment: If you feel you have the skills, it can't hurt to apply (and make it clear in your cover letter why you feel your skills compensate for your lack of certification). If they get a number of applicants, and some _do_ have the cert, there's a good chance they'll just toss your application. But if they do, what have you lost, besides a little time?

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't mean to break any rules of this forum.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just get some kind of IT cert? There are easy enough certifications that don't cost much.

But it does not hurt to apply without a certification. Most certification are over rated in my opinion. Too many people just study for the certification and don't really know the product.

Comment: If you have "equivalent" experience, you should definitely apply, making that clear in your application: "Designed various mail merge letters for cake shop using techniques that are required for ThatCertification"

Comment: There are some circumstances where an employer really needs employees to have certifications, e.g. because they are required for the _company_ to be certified at a certain Microsoft partner level. That would surely not be the case in the OP's situation, though, with a clerk role that demands an cert in word processing.